# What is the correct way to terminate all threads that are 'sub' to main

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am running multiple threads, and when one of the threads sets the global function '**$trade_executed**' to true I want it to kill all other threads and remove them from the global '**$threads**' array.

Then I restart the thread creation process.

Below is a simplified version of my codebase.

3 Threads are created and it looks like 2 threads are deleted but a third thread stays. (for reasons unknown)

Ideally this script would never print '2' or '3' because it would always trigger at '1' minute and kill all threads and reset.

*
**thr.exit** is preferred. I don't want any code pushed from other threads with a **thr.join** after **$trade_executed** is set

```
require 'thread'

class Finnean 
  def initialize
    @lock = Mutex.new
  end

  def digger(minute)  
    sleep(minute * 60)
    coco(minute)
  end 

  def coco(minute)  
    @lock.synchronize {
    puts "coco #{minute}"

      $threads.each do |thr|
      next if thr == Thread.current
      thr.exit
      end
      $trade_executed = true
      Thread.current.exit   
    } 
  end 
end

minutes = [1, 2, 3]
$threads = Array.new 
$trade_executed = false 
abc = Finnean.new

def start_threads(minutes, abc)
  minutes.each do |minute|
    $threads << Thread.new {abc.digger(minute)}
    puts minute
  end
end

start_threads(minutes, abc)

while true
  if $trade_executed != false then 
    count = 0
    $threads.map! do |thr|
      count += 1
      puts "#{thr} & #{thr.status}"
      thr.exit
      $threads.delete(thr)
      puts "Iteration #{count}"
    end

    count = 0
    $threads.each do |thr|
      count += 1
      puts "#{thr}" ##{thr.status}
      puts "Threads Still Left: #{count}"
    end            

    $trade_executed = false
    abc = Finnean.new
    start_threads(minutes, abc)
  end
end
```

Comment: It's really unconventional to use `if ... then` in Ruby in this form. It's normally omitted, just `if ...` Likewise `Array.new` is `[ ]` unless you want to pre-initialize and need to call `new` explicitly. I had to fix up the indentation and removed a bunch of blank lines to make this code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a thread killer that you keep locked up until the first one finishes:

```
# Create two variables that can be passed in to the Thread.new block closure
threads = [ ]
killer = nil

# Create 10 threads, each of which waits a random amount of time before waking up the thread killer
10.times do |n|
  threads << Thread.new do
    sleep(rand(2..25))

    puts "Thread #{n} finished!"
    killer.wakeup
  end
end

# Define a thread killer that will call `kill` on all threads, then `join`
killer = Thread.new(threads) do
  Thread.stop

  threads.each do |thread|
    puts "Killing #{thread}"
    thread.kill
    thread.join
  end
end

# The killer will run last, so wait for that to finish
killer.join
```

You can't force a thread to `exit`, but you can kill it. That generates an exception you could `rescue` and deal with as necessary.